# Rails_admin customisation - How to use layout in a custom controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I have this custom controller:

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
layout 'layouts/rails_admin/application'

def index
end

end
```

I want to use the default rails_admin layout. But I get this error when visiting the path for the index action:

```
undefined local variable or method `dashboard_path' for #<#<Class:0x28a4d68>:0x28a2560>¨
```

How can I use the layout that rails_admin uses?

I need to use a custom controller, actions and view. Just need to include it in rails_admin.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this my way, but please improve this if this is not the best practice..

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  include RailsAdmin::MainHelper
  include RailsAdmin::ApplicationHelper
  include RailsAdmin::Engine.routes.url_helpers

  layout 'layouts/rails_admin/application'

  def index
    @page_name = "custom" # just for title on template
    @is_custom = true # custom marker
  end

end
```

And overide rails admin partial view, by creating a file in
/app/views/layouts/rails_admin/pjax.html.haml

```
- unless @is_custom.eql? true
  / this is default from rails admin, I do not need this for custom controller
  :javascript
    $('.nav.nav-list li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav.nav-list li[data-model="#{@abstract_model.to_param}"]').addClass('active');

  %title= "#{@abstract_model.try(:pretty_name) || @page_name} | #{[_get_plugin_name[0] || 'Rails', _get_plugin_name[1] || 'Admin'].join(' ')}"
  .page-header
    %h1= @page_name
  - flash && flash.each do |key, value|
    .alert{class: "alert-#{key}"}
      %a.close{href: '#', :'data-dismiss' => "alert"}×
      = value
  = breadcrumb
  %ul.nav.nav-tabs
    = menu_for((@abstract_model ? (@object.try(:persisted?) ? :member : :collection) : :root), @abstract_model, @object)
    = content_for :contextual_tabs

/ just render yield for custom controller
= yield
```

Answer (score -1):

Write

```
layout 'rails_admin/application'
```

Instead of

```
layout 'layouts/rails_admin/application'
```

Comment: It does use the rails admin layout the problem is that the routes are not loaded..

Comment: If you want to add something to rails admin then you must inherit your controller from RailsAdmin::ApplicationController class.

Comment: Layout will get included after inheriting from RailsAdmin class